# How to connect one project to another in java through eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, restful-authentication, restful-url

I have a requirement,where in which if i click on a particular link from the main project,the eclipse has to connect to a different sub project,perform the desired action,return the action performed to the main project,and main project renders the desired result,is there any way to do it?

Comment: import the package, instantiate it's class and call it's method(s).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reference a different Java project in Eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10090829/how-to-reference-a-different-java-project-in-eclipse)

Comment: I wonder what Eclipse has to do with this? Eclipse is only an IDE; when you're doing carpentry you also don't ask "so how do I make my workbench open a door?"

Answer (score 2):

You could do it in several different ways, first is simply to define a dependency on a different project that you have in your workspace:

[Eclipse - How to give dependency between projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553677/eclipse-how-to-give-dependency-between-projects)

Then there is of course gradle and maven like ways to define dependencies:

Maven:
[Maven jar dependencies and relations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10721639/maven-jar-dependencies-and-relations)

Gradle:
http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html

Answer (score 0):

Either make one project a library and use that, or use an automated build system like Gradle or Jenkins

Comment: if you could provide any links that might help,would do a lot of good :)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11214292/3485575) answer could be useful to do the Eclipse part